# Conditional Expressions: Error message saying incomplete types

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I can't seem to figure this out. I feel like it so easy that I am missing it. I keep getting an error message saying incomplete types and pointing at the ? What am I doing wrong?

Using a conditional expression, write a statement that increments `numUsers` if `updateDirection` is 1, otherwise decrements `numUsers`.
Ex: if `numUsers` is 8 and `updateDirection` is 1, `numUsers` becomes 9; if `updateDirection` is 0, `numUsers` becomes 7.

Hint: Start with "`numUsers = ...`".

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UpdateNumberOfUsers {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int numUsers;
      int updateDirection;

      numUsers = scnr.nextInt();
      updateDirection = scnr.nextInt();
      String condStr; 
     
      condStr = (numUsers < 8) ? +1 : -1;

      System.out.println("New value is: " + numUsers);
   }
}
```

Comment: The values `+1` and `-1` are integers. Why are you trying to assign them to `condStr`, a string variable? Also you appear to be checking a condition, `numUsers < 8`, which is nothing to do with your stated requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I give you only guidlines and not the complete answer as it looks like an exercice and it's better to do it by yourself.*

Try to write the same line without a ternary operator:

```
if (numUsers < 8) {
    condStr  = +1;
} else {
    condStr = -1;
}
```

This code:

- never update the value of `numUsers`
- doesn't use the value of `updateDirection`
- uses incompatible values (a String set to -1 or +1 makes no sense)

The increment/decrement operators:

```
myVar++; 
myVar--;
```

The equivalent (Note the order of the operators):

```
myVar += 1;
myVar -= 1;
```

The complete form:

```
myVar = myVar + 1;
myVar = myVar - 1;
```

Now you need to use those operators to increment/decrement `numUsers` (so `numUsers++;` or `numUsers--;`) according to the value `updateDirection` (the variable you need to use the `if`condition or in the ternary condition).
There is no need for `condStr`in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the help and advice you both have given me. I was able to complete the assigment! This was the input I put in and everythign outputed perfectly. Thank you jhamon for not giving me the answer and making me use my brain and the guides you provided.

```
if (updateDirection >= 1) {
         numUsers += 1;
      }
      else {
         numUsers -= 1;
      }
```

Comment: That's not a conditional expression. It's an if-statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
numUsers = (updateDirection == 1) ? numUsers + 1 : numUsers - 1;
```